# Thermal diffusion equation with heat per unit length?

Tags: thermodynamics, diffusion

Let us say we have a metal rod. Along that rod there is a rate of heat generation of H per unit length. If we assume we are in the steady state then I would expect us (from the thermal diffusion equation) to have the following expression:
$$\kappa \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}=-\frac{H}{A}$$
Where $A$ is the cross sectional area of the rod. I have however seen this written* instead as: 
$$\kappa \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}=-H$$

Which of these is right and why?

*Blundell, S. and Blundell, K., Concepts in thermal physics, 2nd ed, page 101

Comment: I normally see it as $\dot q/\kappa$ (obviously $H=\dot q$). You might want to check your assumed units of H with the actual units of H as claimed by others (e.g., Blundell$^2$)

Answer (score 1):

H in the second equation must be W/m3 i.e. per unit volume to be correct(Check homogeneity of dimensions). You should also check if the rod is having unit cross-section area,in that case the 2nd equation is also  right.